# How to correctly add a new layer to view in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, calayer

I have an `UIImageView` in a `UIScrollView` and the `UIScrollView`'s `zoomScale` is 1.5.

When I add a new layer to the `UIImageView`'s layer. I want to make the new layer's frame equal to the `UIImageView`'s frame. So I write:

```
newLayer.frame = self.bounds
```

Here `self` stands for the `UIImageView`.

But when running in the simulator, the `newLayer`'s frame is smaller than that of `UIImageView`. It seems that the `newLayer` is still at `zoomScale` = 1, while the `UIImageView` is at `zoomScale` = 1.5 in the `UIScrollView`.

How can I deal with it? I want the `newLayer` and `UIImageView` have the same size in `UIScrollView`.

I also try:

```
newLayer.frame = layer.bounds
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try newLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);   ?

Comment: @johnyu I have tried that. It is the same with : `newLayer.frame = self.bounds` .